# Structuremap with wcf and Entityframework

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, structuremap

I am creating a mvc4 application.The solution structure is given below:[image]

Here DAO layer is implemented in Data.EntityFramework.Service layer is creating services and servicehost for hosting services.CORE layer is for all layering registration.

[image]

Data Entity Layer is :

[image]

I am calling UnitOfWork from servicelayer like below

```
public class CandidateService : ICandidateService
        {
            private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

            public CandidateService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
            {
                this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            }

            //public IList<VW_CANDBASICSEARCH> GetAll()
            //{
            //    try
            //    {
            //        var lstCandidate = _unitOfWork.Repository<VW_CANDBASICSEARCH>().All();
            //        var list = lstCandidate.ToList<VW_CANDBASICSEARCH>();
            //        return list;
            //    }
            //    catch (Exception er)
            //    {
            //        throw er;
            //    }
            //}

            public IList<VW_CANDBASICSEARCH> GetSearchCandidate(string strName, string strLocation, string strProfession, string strSkill)
            {
                var lstCandidate = _unitOfWork.Repository<VW_CANDBASICSEARCH>().All().ToList<VW_CANDBASICSEARCH>();
                var lstSearchCan = from can in lstCandidate
                                   where ((strName == null || strName.Length == 0 || (can.CAND_NAME).ToUpper().Contains(strName.ToUpper()))
                                            && (strLocation == null || strLocation.Length == 0 || can.CAND_LOCATION.Equals(strLocation))
                                            && (strProfession == null || strProfession.Length == 0 || can.CAND_PROFESSION.Equals(strProfession))
                                            && (strSkill == null || strSkill.Length == 0 || can.CAND_SKILL.Equals(strProfession)))
                                   select can;
                return lstSearchCan.ToList<VW_CANDBASICSEARCH>();
            }


            public TBLCANDIDATE_HEADER CreateCandidate(TBLCANDIDATE_HEADER Candidate)
            {
                Candidate.ObjectState = ObjectState.Added;
                _unitOfWork.Repository<TBLCANDIDATE_HEADER>().Insert(Candidate);
                return Candidate;

            }
        }
```

In CORE layer I am registering Data and Business like the following;

```
public class BusinessLogicServiceModule : Registry
        {


            public BusinessLogicServiceModule()
            {
                For(typeof(IHrmsRepository<>)).Use(typeof(Repository<>));
                For<IUnitOfWork>().Use<UnitOfWork>();


            }
        }
```

In service host I am implementing this following http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/07/30/integrating-structuremap-with-wcf/
In IHRMS.WEB I am writing in Global.asax.cs Application_start the following

```
 protected void Application_Start()
            {
                AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

                 WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
                FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
                RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);


                ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.AddRegistry(new BusinessLogicServiceModule()));

                ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.AddRegistry(new ControllerDependency()));
                ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new StructureMapControllerFactory());

                BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

                AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
            }
```

But when I am running it is giving the following error:
**StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily IHRMS.DAO.Infrastructure.IUnitOfWork, IHRMS.DAO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null**

I am using Structuremap as DI.
Can some one plz help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks good to me.

I typically address these ambiguous structuremap errors by doing the following:

- verify your injected classes have:

  - public constructors
  - the construction parameter dependencies have also been defined in the registry
- step through the 'build-up' workflow

  - make sure the dependencies are defined before they are called for
- make sure of the AssertConfigurationIsValid and WhatDoIHave methods off the ObjectFactory to visually confirm you have a valid dependency configuration

Most of issues are resolved in the workflow validation step, if a dependency is configured 'after' is has been asked for structuremap will throw a 202 error.

Also just to confirm the IUnitOfWork being configured and the IUnitOfWork dependency are the same object right (IE: they are the same namespace and what not)?

Sorry I don't have an answer at this time but if you have more information I would be happy to help.

Thanks,
wm